# Nautilus: Automatic scroll upwards in case of new file possible?

Tags: nautilus, gui, filemanager, ux

Years ago I used a mac with OSX and it had one feature which I really miss on Ubuntu. Let's say I had my file manager open, showing the Downloads folder. When I would then switch to the browser and download a file, and then switch back to the file manager, the new file would be out of scope because it appeared above the last file on top. The file manager in OSX would then automatically scroll up to show the new file. Currently in Ubuntu however, I have to manually scroll up before seeing the file in Nautilus.

I've been using Ubuntu for years already and I love it, but I really really miss this tiny feature because it happens multiple times per day for me.

Would anybody know whether this already exists in some form? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I couldn't find any option on `/org/gnome/nautilus/` of dconf database. Probably you should [file a feature request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/) and have a lot of patience or offer a PR (and convince them to accept it).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PabloBianchi. I opened a discussion about it here: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/feature-request-automatic-scroll-upwards-in-case-of-new-file-feedback-needed/10747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is more or less already done in the nightly versions. One of the Gnome devs [suggested testing the nightly version](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/feature-request-automatic-scroll-upwards-in-case-of-new-file-feedback-needed/10747/2?u=kramer65) and that works great. For others that want to test it, I ran the following to install and run the nightly version of Nautilus:

```sh
# Add the gnome nightly repo to flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists gnome-nightly https://nightly.gnome.org/gnome-nightly.flatpakrepo

# Install Nautilus nightly
flatpak install gnome-nightly org.gnome.NautilusDevel

# Run it
flatpak run org.gnome.NautilusDevel//master
```

After this you can add it to your sidebar favorites so that you can use that instead of the default installed version.

This totally solves my problem, and I'll run the nightly from now on. I don't know when this will be released in Gnome, let alone on Ubuntu. I asked the Gnome devs about it in the thread linked above, so we might get an answer there. In the meantime you can use the nightly version.

In case you do test the nightly version; please provide feedback to the gnome devs in the linked thread above. They love to hear from you!